Перенос таблицы из одного .docx в другой при помощи python
Есть два файла "Шаблон договора.docx" и "таблица.docx".
В "таблица.docx" находится только таблица, а в "Шаблон договора.docx" есть несколько строк (это будущий договор) и среди всего текста есть метка "{table}" которая означает место, куда нужно вставить таблицу из файла "таблица.docx".
Сохранить это дело нужно в третьем файле "Шаблон договора с таблицей.docx".
Но проблема в том, что в я не могу перенести таблицу из файла в файл в таком же виде. Она переносится либо списком списков, где указаны все значения, либо в необходимом месте появляется <docx.table.Table object at 0x0000022F7F5442D0>, либо таблица показывается без рамок и выравниваний.
Вроде бы задача не сложная, но третий день ломаю голову. Помогите пожалуйста.
from docx import Document

# Открываем файлы
template_doc = Document("Шаблон договора.docx")
table_doc = Document("таблица.docx")

# Получаем таблицу из таблица.docx
table = table_doc.tables[0]

# Находим метку "{table}" в шаблоне и вставляем таблицу
for paragraph in template_doc.paragraphs:
    if "{table}" in paragraph.text:
        table_paragraph = paragraph.insert_paragraph_before("")
        table_paragraph._element.clear_content()

        for row in table.rows:
            new_row = table_paragraph.add_run()
            for cell in row.cells:
                new_row.add_text(cell.text)
            table_paragraph.add_run().add_break()  # добавляем разрыв строки после строки таблицы

        # Удаляем абзац с меткой "{table}"
        template_doc._element.body.remove(paragraph._element)
        break

# Сохраняем измененный документ
template_doc.save("Шаблон договора с таблицей.docx")

Мои файлы для примера

А добавить объект table в нужный параграф пробовал? Я так понимаю в параграфе должен быть объект таблица, вместо которого и нужно присвоить table.
